# Class styles not being applied to <img>s

Tags: html, css

Here's a strange one. This seems pretty simple but just isn't working.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLssgw1m/1/)

I have images within a container. Images with `class="1"` should take up the full width of the container div. Images with `class="2"` should be able to fit 2 images side by side, taking up the full width of the container div. Images with `class="3"` should be able to fit 3... you get the idea.

However, even though the classes are being applied (inspect the elements!), the styles are not. The only thing that seems to work is a general style for `#container img`, which Iyou can test in the fiddle by removing the ".1" or ".2" from either style. As soon as you add `.1`, the images no longer take on the style, even if they are `class="1"`!

All I can think tis that maybe  tags don't support the class attr? But I don't think that's true.

Comment: I believe the class names cannot start with a number. Try an alpha instead (i.e. a, b, c)

Comment: HTML5 allows class names to begin with a number, however CSS does not allow selectors to begin with numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS class selectors cannot start with a number.

Use an attribute selector or (more sensibly) better class names.

Comment: for seconds you were faster than me ;)

Comment: fastest vote ups i have see in a while, just need few words.

Comment: Heh, something I probably should have known. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

> In CSS, [*identifiers*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) [...] cannot start with a digit.

That means that class selectors **can** start with a digit, but you must **escape** it properly.

To escape a digit `d`, you can use `\00003d` or `\3d`  (note the whitespace).

For example,

```css
.\31 {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">Foo bar</div>
```